# Pointer receiver method compilation problem: Cannot call a pointer method on 'MyObj{}'

Tags: go, pointers, methods

I have the following method defined:

```
func (o *MyObj) parse(something string) string {
    // Do stuff
}
```

This code **(1)** compiles just fine:

```
(&MyObj{}).parse(myString)
```

This code **(2)** compiles too:

```
m := MyObj{}
m.parse(myString)
```

But this code **(3)** doesn't compile:

```
MyObj{}.parse(myString)
```

With the error

> Cannot call a pointer method on 'MyObj{}'

My questions:

1. Why **(2)** compiles? I read that [T method set doesn't include *T method set](https://golang.org/doc/faq#different_method_sets), hence I'd expect it not to compile.
2. Given **(2)** compiles, why wouldn't **(3)** compile??

Comment: Are you asking about the rationale of Go's designers or for an authoritative source that explains the behaviour you observe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in **(2)** `m.parse(myString)` compiles because [calling](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls) the method on it equals to addressing *and then* calling the method on the pointer, i.e. `(&m).parse(myString)`:

> If `x` is addressable and `&x`'s method set contains `m`, `x.m()` is shorthand for `(&x).m()`

However this shorthand is not available in **(3)** `MyObj{}.parse(myString)` because the literal `MyObj{}` is **not addressable**. From the [specs: "Address operators"](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators):

> The operand must be addressable, that is, either a variable, pointer indirection, or slice indexing operation; [...or other cases that don't apply].

And `MyObj{}` being a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) is neither of those; whereas `m` from example **(2)** is a variable.

Finally the same section about address operators specifies an exception that explains why the example in **(1)** `(&MyObj{}).parse(myString)` compiles:

> As an exception to the addressability requirement, `x` may also be a (possibly parenthesized) composite literal.

In this case you can take its address, parenthesize it and call the method, which is syntactically similar to the compiler shorthand for (2).

Comment: The difficulty stems from the rather confusing terminology used by the language spec. `MyObj{}` is [not strictly speaking _addressable_](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) but, because it's a composite literal, [taking its address is legal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals).